# mcollective mco facts command blank result output

Tags: puppet, facter

I have install mcollective with activemq but when i run following command it ran successfully but result is blank, i want to see report output.

```
[root@vsoslp01 tmp]# mco find
vsopspss01
vsopsmgs01


[root@vsoslp01 tmp]# mco facts architecture
Report for fact: architecture


Finished processing 2 / 2 hosts in 293.91 ms
```

Installed plugins

```
[root@vsoslp01 tmp]# mco plugin doc
Please specify a plugin. Available plugins are:

Agents:
  puppet                    Run Puppet agent, get its status, and enable/disable it
  rpcutil                   General helpful actions that expose stats and internals to SimpleRPC clients

Aggregate:
  average                   Displays the average of a set of numeric values
  boolean_summary           Aggregate function that will transform true/false values into predefined strings.
  sum                       Determine the total added value of a set of values
  summary                   Displays the summary of a set of results

Data Queries:
  agent                     Meta data about installed MColletive Agents
  fstat                     Retrieve file stat data for a given file
  puppet                    Information about Puppet agent state
  resource                  Information about Puppet managed resources

Discovery Methods:
  flatfile                  Flatfile based discovery for node identities
  mc                        MCollective Broadcast based discovery
  stdin                     STDIN based discovery for node identities

Validator Plugins:
  array                     Validates that a value is included in a list
  ipv4address               Validates that a value is an ipv4 address
  ipv6address               Validates that a value is an ipv6 address
  length                    Validates that the length of a string is less or equal to a specified value
  puppet_resource           Validates the validity of a Puppet resource type and name
  puppet_server_address     Validates that a string is a valid Puppet Server and Port for the Puppet agent
  puppet_tags               Validates that a comma seperated list of tags are valid Puppet class names
  puppet_variable           Validates that a variable name is a valid Puppet name
  regex                     Validates that a string matches a supplied regular expression
  shellsafe                 Validates that a string is shellsafe
  typecheck                 Validates that a value is of a certain type
```

EDIT:

```
[root@vsoslp01 logs]# mco inventory vsopspss01
Inventory for vsopspss01:

   Server Statistics:
                      Version: 2.4.1
                   Start Time: Tue Feb 18 13:40:58 -0500 2014
                  Config File: /etc/mcollective/server.cfg
                  Collectives: mcollective
              Main Collective: mcollective
                   Process ID: 7694
               Total Messages: 14
      Messages Passed Filters: 14
            Messages Filtered: 0
             Expired Messages: 0
                 Replies Sent: 13
         Total Processor Time: 0.32 seconds
                  System Time: 0.09 seconds

   Agents:
      discovery       puppet          rpcutil

   Data Plugins:
      agent           fstat           puppet
      resource

   Configuration Management Classes:
      No classes applied

   Facts:
      mcollective => 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you populate the facts file?  MCollective reads a yaml file contianing all the facts.  If it's empty then it won't see any facts.

[Populating the facts file](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/deploy/standard.html#populate-the-fact-file)

Comment: I have open `/etc/mcollective/facts.yaml` file and contents are `mcollective: 1` what is this? do i need something here?

Comment: Got it what you saying!  `/usr/bin/facter --puppet --yaml > /etc/mcollective/facts.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied Puppet manifests using the `puppet-apply` command? Does querying inventory on those systems return anything at all?

```
$ mco inventory vsopspss01
```